# Title Frame Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, frame-title

How can I insert the title of a frame in beamer section?
I try to use: `\frametitle` but it does not work.

This is my code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\definecolor{crimson}{HTML}{A51C30}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=white,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{author in head/foot}{bg=crimson,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title in head/foot}{bg=crimson,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date in head/foot}{bg=crimson,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{bg=crimson,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{bg=crimson,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{external link}{bg=crimson,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white,fg=crimson}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\normalfont,family=\rmfamily,size=\Huge}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=text!50}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=crimson!50}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=30pt,text margin right=30pt}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.5ex,dp=2.5ex,right]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\textbf{\insertshorttitle: mongoDB }\insertsubtitle\quad\today\hspace*{30pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\title{Basi di dati non relazionali}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{logo.png}           
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{SQL vs NoSQL}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}

            \item memorizza i documenti in file di tipo \textbf{JSON};
            \item orientato ai documenti
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the line `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}`.